# How to extract the value returned by function token-generator : (delay (token-generator state))

Tags: clojure

I am trying to use the value from 'new' in another function, but it looks like the below given piece of code is faulty.

I am unable to figure out why.

I am wrapping the function 'token-generator' inside a delay because I only want it to run the function 'token-generator' to get a new token when the current old token value expires.

```
(def r (let [new (delay (token-generator state))]
  (if (compare-and-set! token old new)
      new
      @token)))

(prn r)  ->  nil
(prn @r) ->  NullPointerException   clojure.core/deref-future (core.clj:2208)
```

Please assist! Thanks!

Edit1 : 'token' is a variable holding the last token received, 'old' being the last token used. They can differ, in the scope of the program.

Edit2 : Added @token (last line)

Comment: Is your goal to hold a "valid" token whenever you request it?  I'd write that as a function then and keep the last token in an atom.  The function to request the valid token can then check for the timeout.

Comment: @cfrick I am holding a "valid token", what I want to do is, when the token is expired to call this function which contains the "compare-and-set! token old new", where "new" holds the delay to generate a new token, and return that.

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you gave more detail in the question, like the expected input & output data, and missing code (i.e. what is `token`?).

---

You probably meant to deref `new` like:

```
(if (compare-and-set! token old @new)
```

See [The Clojure CheatSheet](http://jafingerhut.github.io/cheatsheet/clojuredocs/cheatsheet-tiptip-cdocs-summary.html) for an overview.  Look up the definitions of `atom`, `delay`, `deliver`, `deref` (aka `@`).

You probably also want `@token` on the last line.

Comment: Thank you @AlanThompson, but how do I implement the desired behavior? i.e. to run the function 'token-generator' to get a new token only when the current old token value expires, given the token value is stored as an atom.

Comment: (if (compare-and-set! token old @new) worked.. Thanks Alan!! @AlanThompson